# Compiler Error Message: CS0135: 'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3. I have created a strongly typed view that has a form. At the bottom of the page I have and ActionLink

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = Model.UserId})
```

this will allow the user to edit the information. When I run the app I get the following error.

```
  Compiler Error Message: CS0135: 'Model' conflicts with the declaration
 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model'
```

What could this be.

Answer (score 29):

I guess somewhere in your view you have used a strongly typed helper with a lambda expression using the reserved `Model` keyword. Like for example:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.SomeProperty)
```

it should be:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeProperty)
```

or any other name.

Comment: Darin, I am using @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.SomeProperty) @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.SomeProperty2) @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.SomeProperty3) and everything is fine.

Comment: @Evan, well, try replacing `@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.SomeProperty)` with `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.SomeProperty)`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov, I had this issue as well. Brilliant that you recognized the cause by looking at the exception and without the actual code. For me, this issue only started occurring after I added an Action in which I tried to pass routeValues like this: @Html.Action("_EmployeeList", new { id = Model.Id})

Answer (score 4):

I found simply replacing the capital M with a small m solved this. i.e. from

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.SomeProperty)
```

to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SomeProperty)
```

Perhaps it is more ambiguous, but it is less of a change if you want to keep things similar to the way they were.