# Render span element with text from Model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html

Is there a way to render text into a `span` element when an ASP MVC 3 view loads? For instance
if I have `<span id="territoryName"></span>` how would I load the data from `Model.Region` into the `span` element as text?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Razor you can use the following.

```
<span id="territoryName">@Model.Region</span>
```

Note: the value will be HTML-encoded.

Without HTML-encoding:

```
<span id="territoryName">@Html.Raw(Model.Region)</span>
```

Comment: The page really doesn't like the `Model.Region` part. With both I get the following error: `'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model'`

Comment: See this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204301/compiler-error-message-cs0135-model-conflicts-with-the-declaration-system-w

Comment: Used both the answer provided as well as the above question to solve this issue. Thanks!