# Url.Action How to add parameter value from the model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, url-action

In controller I have the action "GetPhoto":

```
public FileResult GetPhoto(int id)
{
    ...
}
```

Also, I have Razor code where I'am trying to dynamically add ID parameter from the model:

```
@model ISPIS.Models.KodFazeBiljke
...
<img src="@Url.Action("GetPhoto", new { id = model.KodFazeBiljkeId })" alt="" width="250" height="190"/>
```

However, it's not possible to write "id = model.KodFazeBiljkeId" because, model does not exist in the current context.

Any solution? Thanks!

Comment: you declare the model with `@model`, but you use it as `Model`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your approach should work -- just have to refer to the model with the upper-case `Model`:

```
<img src='@Url.Action("GetPhoto", new { id = Model.KodFazeBiljkeId })' alt="" width="250" height="190"/>
```

Comment: Still not working! I got: Compiler Error Message: CS0135: 'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model'

Comment: @Branislav You might need to change code elsewhere in your view.  See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6204388/1001985

Comment: Suppose in this case, if we change the value of KodFazeBiljkeId in some textbox, then will the Url.Action get updated according to with that value?