# MVC : foreach loop gives System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Confused here. Just want to use the sample data in the constructor to display one field and then loop through the one record :

```
public class MikesViewModel
{
    public MikesClass MikesClass { get; set; }

    public List<MikesClass> MikesClassList { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult MikesView()
{   
    var viewClassModel = new MikesViewModel();

    viewClassModel.MikesClass = new MikesClass();

    viewClassModel.MikesClassList = new List<MikesClass> { new MikesClass() {} };

    return View(viewClassModel);    
}
```

View is the problem : the `foreach` won't work if I take out `@Html.DropDownListFor` :

```
@using AAA.Models    
@model MikesViewModel  


@Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.MikesClass.Name) 


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MikesClass.Id, 
                          new SelectList(Model.MikesClassList, "Id", "Name"))

}

**** This foreach won't work if I take out the ^ above line ** :**

@foreach (var item in Model.MikesClassList)
{

@item.Name
}
```

The weird thing is, if I take out the :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MikesClass.Id, new SelectList(Model.MikesClassList, "Id", "Name"))
```

the `@foreach (var item in Model.MikesClassList)` doesn't work and gives the error :

`'Model' conflicts with the declaration 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>.Model'`

How can I get the foreach to work? Not understanding this.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6204301/compiler-error-message-cs0135-model-conflicts-with-the-declaration-system-w)

Comment: I actually saw that answer before I posted mine, but I guess I didn't understand what was going on yet, . . but yes, it was the same problem I had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't call things "Model" or "model" in the view.  That's probably confusing the view engine.  Lines like this, for example:

```
@Html.EditorFor(Model => Model.MikesClass.Name)
```

You're declaring a variable in `EditorFor` called `Model`, but there's already a built-in variable in the view engine called `Model`.  When you dereference it as `Model.MikesClass` which one are you referring to?  You have another one called `model` here:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.MikesClass.Id, new SelectList(Model.MikesClassList, "Id", "Name"))
```

While `Model` and `model` aren't reserved words in C#, it's best to consider them "reserved" in views.  Basically, it's best to use meaningful names for your variables and not overly-generic ones.

`foreach` works just fine, but other lines in that view have already confused the engine that it doesn't know what to do when it gets to the `foreach`.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I didn't even realize I was using a variable there (I guess I copied that from an example somewhere that had : (Model => Model...). If I use (r => r.MikesClass.Name) the foreach works. This lambda stuff can get confusing but provides easy coding.